# Cleaning up orphaned WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service endpoint that I am opening from a windows forms app. Sometimes the forms app crashes, and when I restart the application I cannot reopen the WCF service endpoint because the port is in use.

I can find tools that will let me kill this orphaned connection so that I can open it again (rebooting or disable/enable network adapter), but I am curious to know if there is a programmatic means to locate and kill these connections(or attach and reuse them).

This is an example of how I am opening the connection.

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:{0}/{1}", port, serviceName));
this._ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(this, uri);
_ServiceHost.Open();
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction? I am more interested in how to recover this orphaned port/url than how to handle a crash.

Comment: If you put it in a using statement, won't that automatically dispose it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont want to dispose it. It needs to stay open for the lifetime of the application. If the application closes correctly, it shuts down correctly. If the application crashes, I have to resort to a reboot or other tool to free up the port.

Comment: Do you try to dispose it via unhandled exception handlers? See this url for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Its not an application wide instance. Its only available when two forms are active.